# Save picture in web api on file system

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to write a method to upload image on file system , so i create a web api and 
write this method :

```
 public class ProductPictureController : ApiController
   {
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddProductPicture()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        var textInfo = result.Contents[0].ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var image = result.Contents[1];
        var fullyQualifyFileName = image.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "").Replace("-", "");           
        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/ProductPicture/" + fullyQualifyFileName);

        return Ok("done");
    }
}
```

and i want to access `SaveAs` method for write `image.SaveAs(Path)`, but i can not access to it, is there any way to do like this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image.SaveAs`? umm I think what's accessible for web is the `HttpContext.Current.Request.SaveAs`